# What are「熄み」's etymology and meaning

Tags: meaning, words, etymology, song-lyrics

「熄み」appears in a song「インフェルノ」

> 照らすは闇 僕らは歩き慣れてきた日々も淘汰
>   夢は安泰な暮らしだが 刺激不足故にタラタラ
>   照らすは**熄み** 僕らの歩き慣れていた道はどこだ
>   時はたまに癪だが 温もりに包まれ只

It is pronounced やみ in the song, the same as 闇. I have never seen this word before. And strangely enough I can't find out much about it. [A page that strives to explain the song lyrics](https://www.teaandsoup-p.com/blog/?p=11346) shows 「熄み」 in the lyrics but a couple lines down in the explanation section it is replaced by 「闇」. Do they have the same meaning? What is 「熄み」's deal (etymology, currency, literary examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flexibility in Japanese written forms

Written Japanese has two layers to it -- the words as pronounced, and the words as written.  This double-layering allows authors to play around with nuance in ways that just aren't possible in other languages, like 月光【ムーンライト】 or 巾着【さいふ】 or 紅葉【はっぱのはなび】.

### 熄【や】み in specific

Your example isn't quite as much of a stretch, as や(み) is actually one of the recognized *kun'yomi* for the kanji 熄.  See also the entries [at WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MMC%E7%86%84) or [at the Japanese Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%86%84).  Note that this is a so-called 表外字【ひょうがいじ】 or literally "off-the-chart character", as it is not included in the list of 常用漢字【じょうようかんじ】 or "general-use kanji", and this character is therefore somewhat rare.

In terms of nuance, 闇【やみ】 refers to "darkness", while 熄【や】み brings in shades of "ceasing, halting, disappearing".

### Etymology (word origins)

Both terms reflect a root verb *yamu* meaning something close to the 熄 sense: "stopping, extinguishing, disappearing".  This is related in turn with words like:

- 止【や】む: something ongoing stops, such as the rain
- 止【や】める: to quit doing something, such as annoying your sister  :)
- 辞【や】める: to resign, to quit, such as a job or post
- 病【や】む: to suffer from something, to become sick (probably from the way that sickness often led to someone stopping their normal routine, and possibly even "stopping" completely, i.e. dying)
- 病【やまい】: disease, sickness
- 病【や】ます: (*archaic*) to afflict someone, to inflict something on someone
- 闇【やみ】: darkness (from the way the light extinguishes or disappears)

Learning the root forms can open up all kinds of related terms.  I find that my understanding of Japanese is much richer when I learn the connections and associations between words.

#### Speculation

This root *yamu* may be related to the term 黄泉【よみ】 for "the underworld, the land of the dead".  In the oldest texts, the word also showed a combining root reading of *yomo*.  The [entry at the English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BB%84%E6%B3%89#Japanese) states that this may be an ablaut (vowel-shift) relative of 山【やま】, from the way that mountains were associated with the dead in ancient times.  That entry has no sources listed for this derivation, but the sound-shift alternation //a// ↔ //o// is apparent in various other terms rooted in ancient vocabulary, where //a// seems to indicate "outward" and //o// "inward".

*(Full disclosure: I've edited that 黄泉 entry.  However, I did not add that particular derivation.)*

Anyway, make of this last part what you will.  :)

---

Please comment if the above does not address your question.